# Warum klingt "treffen uns um 8" richtig und "treffen uns um 20" falsch?

Tags: word-usage

Zeitangaben, bei denen die Stunde größer als 12 ist, funktionieren nur mit angehängtem "Uhr":

"Wir treffen uns um 23 Uhr."

vs.

"Wir treffen uns um 11." - "Morgens?" - "Nein, nachts!"

Obwohl die 24-Stunden-Zählung bereits im [späten Mittelalter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-mal-12-Stunden-Z%C3%A4hlung) eingeführt wurde, widerspricht "Wir treffen uns um 23." dem Sprachgefühl. Vielleicht hängt das mit dem Ziffernblatt analoger Uhren zusammen, vielleicht wurzelt dieses Sprachgefühl in Zeiten vor der 24er-Zählung. Was lässt sich dazu sagen, und wie(so) erhält sich so eine eigentlich unpraktische (siehe den kleinen Dialog oben) Konvention?

Comment: +1, interessante Frage! Ich glaube ja, es hat etwas mit dem Sprachrhythmus zu tun - fast alle Zahlen bis 12 haben nur eine Silbe, so dass die Sätze einen schönen Jambus haben - selbst die zweite Silbe von "sieben" ist halbwegs verschluckbar. Die Zahlen ab 13 sind dagegen durchgängig mindestens zweisilbig und mit der Endung "-zehn" oder "-undzwanzig" auch aufwändiger zu sprechen.

Comment: @Jan Andererseits klingt "Wir treffen uns um 20 Uhr" wiederum vollkommen richtig, und das ist ja noch aufwendiger als "Wir treffen uns um 20". Es geht hier also eher um die Unterscheidung 12-Stunden-Uhr vs. 24-Stunden-Uhr.

Comment: @Hackworth so wie ich das sehe geht es mehr um die subjektive Wahrnehmung, d.h. das Sprachgefühl. Mit dem Zusatz "Uhr" werden diese Sätze mit den Zahlen ab 13 wieder jambisch, d.h. sie klingen "runder". Ja, sie sind komplizierter zu sprechen und länger, aber manch einer mag die dadurch gegebene Präzision. Der Fragesteller selbst findet die 12-Uhr-Zählung ja auch unpraktisch.

Comment: Deutlich wird es auch, wenn man treffen durch streiten ersetzt. "Wir streiten uns um 8" klingt nach eine Verabredung um 8 Uhr. Bei "wir streiten uns um 20", fragt man unwillkürlich um was für 20 es bei dem Streit geht.

Comment: Ich verwende z.B. "Wir treffen uns um 20" gelegentlich mit der Bedeutung "Wir treffen uns um xx Uhr 20", also um die Minuten anzugeben wenn die Stunden klar ist. In Österreich ist das zumindest umgangssprachlich recht verbreitet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Aus praktischen Gründen bürgerte sich aber etwa im 16. Jahrhundert wieder eine künstliche Trennung ein, [...]

Zitat aus Deinem Wikipedia-Link. Das zeigt, dass trotz der frühen Einführung, die Menschen aus Gewohnheit oder Bequemlichkeit die 12er Einteilung weiterverwendeten. Was sie in manchen Gegenden immer noch tun, siehe die Angaben "a.m." und "p.m." im Englischen.

Die analoge Uhr ist in 12 Stunden aufgeteilt und analoge Uhren sind weit verbreitet (Kirchtürme, Bahnhöfe, Armbanduhren). Kindern die Zeit beizubringen ist oft auch mit analogen Uhren einfacher, da sie sich die Aufteilung der Stunde bildlich vorstellen können.

Was dazu führt, dass niemand "viertel nach 20" sagt, analog (kein Wortspiel ;)) zu Deinem Beispiel oben. Diese Angaben werden mit den Ziffern auf dem Ziffernblatt verbunden, nicht mit der Uhrzeit. Bei "treffen wir uns um 11" wird "Uhr" *nicht* weggelassen. Vergleiche die Aussage bei 1 Uhr:

> Wir treffen uns um ein Uhr.
>   Wir treffen uns um eins.

Diese Art der Zeitangabe beruht auf den *Zahlen* auf dem Ziffernblatt, nicht auf den *Uhrzeiten* die sie repräsentieren. Da es (auf den meisten) Ziffernblättern keine 20 gibt, sagt auch keiner "wir treffen uns um 20". Tradition, Macht der Gewohnheit, so haben wir es schon immer gemacht, gefangen in der Abstraktionsfalle, nenn es wie Du willst. Auf der Uhr stehen halt Zahlen, keine Uhrzeiten.

Comment: Du schreibst 'Bei "treffen wir uns um 11" wird "Uhr" nicht weggelassen' - das sehe ich anders. Dennoch überzeugen mich das "viertel nach 20"-Argument und die "Macht der Gewohnheit".

Comment: @Olaf: Ich meinte damit, daß "Uhr" dort zwar nicht steht, aber nicht, weil es weggelassen wurde, sondern weil es nie da war. Es ist ein Zahl, keine Uhrzeit.

Answer (score 3):

In der Zeitmessung hat sich sowohl das [babylonische Sexagesimalsystem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimalsystem) (60 Minuten = 1 Stunde, 30 Tage = 1 Monat) als auch das sich daraus ableitende Duodezimalsystem (12 Monate = 1 Jahr, 24 Stunden = 1 Tag) bis heute erhalten. Auch in der Namensgebung unserer Zahlen spiegelt sich das wider (bis 12 ist jeweils ein eigenes Wort vorhanden).

Demnach wurde ein Tag in 24 Stunden eingeteilt. Die erste öffentliche Turmuhr, die 1336 n. Chr. in Mailand gebaut wurde, teilte den Tag noch in 4 mal 6 Stunden ein; danach gab es Turmuhren mit 24-Stunden-Schlagwerk, jedoch haben sich seit dem Bau der Turmuhr in Breslau 1368 n. Chr. öffentliche Uhren mit 12-Stunden-Schlagwerk durchgesetzt.<sup>[Trustedwatch](http://www.trustedwatch.de/wissen/historie)</sup>

Dies geschah sicherlich auch aus praktischen Gründen, um ein „Verzählen“ bei Uhrzeiten über 12 zu vermeiden.<sup>[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-Stunden-Z%C3%A4hlung)</sup> Man hat die Uhrzeit nach dem abgezählten Schlag der Turmuhrglocke angegeben:

> *„Hört, ihr Herrn, und lasst euch sagen,
>
>   unsre Glock hat zehn geschlagen!
>
>   Zehn Gebote setzt’ Gott ein;
>
>   gib, dass wir gehorsam sein!“*<sup>Nachtwächterlied 18. Jh.</sup>

Diese Zeitangabe wird bis heute im Sprachgebrauch beibehalten, trotz der mit der [ISO 8601](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) heute international eingeführten 24-Stunden-Zählung.